# MailMessage.BodyFormat throw an unknown error when it equals to MailFormat.Html

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using **visual studio 2010** with **.Net Framework 4.0**, and trying to send a email.
When I use **MailMessage** which is defined in **System.Web.Mail**, everything works fine, until I set `MailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html`, It will throw out an unknown error, but this error will not happen if `MailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text`.
 
Although I use **System.Net.Mail** `MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true` to reach my goal, I still want to know what cause this unknown error, and is there any way to solve it?

this code below will throw an unknow error like https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dUPP.jpg

```
public static string SendMail(string strsender, string strReceiver, string strsubject, string strbody)
        {

            try
            {
                MailMessage vMailMessage = new MailMessage();
                char[] separator = { ',' };

                vMailMessage.From = GetEmailAddress(strsender.Trim(), separator); //寄件人 //存取被拒
                vMailMessage.To = GetEmailAddress(strReceiver.Trim(), separator); //收件人                    
                //vMailMessage.Cc = GetEmailAddress(vDataRow["CC"].ToString().Trim(), separator);       //副本                    
                //vMailMessage.Bcc = GetEmailAddress(vDataRow["BCC"].ToString().Trim(), separator);     //密件副本  
                vMailMessage.Subject = strsubject.Trim(); //主旨

                vMailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
                vMailMessage.Body = strbody;

                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "Webmail";  //設定Mail伺服器
                SmtpMail.Send(vMailMessage); //發送mail
                //SmtpMail.Send(vMailMessage.From, vMailMessage.To, vMailMessage.Subject, vMailMessage.Body); //發送mail

                return "ok";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And this code below will able to send an email with text form like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd2h6.jpg

```
public static string SendMail(string strsender, string strReceiver, string strsubject, string strbody)
        {

            try
            {
                MailMessage vMailMessage = new MailMessage();
                char[] separator = { ',' };

                vMailMessage.From = GetEmailAddress(strsender.Trim(), separator); //寄件人 //存取被拒
                vMailMessage.To = GetEmailAddress(strReceiver.Trim(), separator); //收件人                    
                //vMailMessage.Cc = GetEmailAddress(vDataRow["CC"].ToString().Trim(), separator);       //副本                    
                //vMailMessage.Bcc = GetEmailAddress(vDataRow["BCC"].ToString().Trim(), separator);     //密件副本  
                vMailMessage.Subject = strsubject.Trim(); //主旨

                vMailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
                vMailMessage.Body = strbody;

                SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "Webmail";  //設定Mail伺服器
                SmtpMail.Send(vMailMessage); //發送mail
                //SmtpMail.Send(vMailMessage.From, vMailMessage.To, vMailMessage.Subject, vMailMessage.Body); //發送mail

                return "ok";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: It just say unknown error, just a second, I can upload that image.

Comment: @Ben https://imgur.com/a/1Djq5uI just like this

Comment: The error in English may be helpful.

Comment: It isn't yet a [mcve], since I can't copy it into a console app and run it.

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mail.mailformat?view=netframework-4.7.2) documentation, MailFormat is now obsolete. The warning should come up as:

> Warning
>
> This API is now obsolete. Recommended alternative: System.Net.Mail.

I would suggest to use `MailMessage.AlternateViews` property to provide HTML and text alternative for a `MailMessage`.

More on [MailMessage.AlternateViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews?view=netframework-4.7.2). As per AlternateViews documentation:

> Use the AlternateViews property to specify copies of an email message
>   in different formats. For example, if you send a message in HTML, you
>   might also want to provide a plain text version in case some of the
>   recipients use email readers that cannot display HTML content. For an
>   example that demonstrates creating a message with alternate views, see
>   AlternateViews.

Your modified code looks like below:

```
public static string SendMail(string strsender, string strReceiver, string strsubject, string strbody)
    {

        try
        {
            MailMessage vMailMessage = new MailMessage();
            char[] separator = { ',' };

            vMailMessage.From = GetEmailAddress(strsender.Trim(), separator); //寄件人 //存取被拒
            vMailMessage.To.Add(GetEmailAddress(strReceiver.Trim(), separator)); //收件人                    
            //vMailMessage.Cc = GetEmailAddress(vDataRow["CC"].ToString().Trim(), separator);       //副本                    
            //vMailMessage.Bcc = GetEmailAddress(vDataRow["BCC"].ToString().Trim(), separator);     //密件副本  
            vMailMessage.Subject = strsubject.Trim(); //主旨

            vMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            vMailMessage.Body = strbody;

            SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "Webmail";  //設定Mail伺服器
            SmtpMail.Send(vMailMessage); //發送mail

            return "ok";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, I know that, but our company still exist lots of system using .Net Framework 3.0, visual studio 2005 or lower, so I want to know if there is any way to use their code without modification. Any change may cause an unexpected result.

Comment: i think you dont need MailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html

Comment: if using System.Net.Mail, you can simply use .IsBodyHtml = true. the statement MailMessage.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html is redundant

Comment: use System.Web.Mail or System.Net.Mail, not both

Comment: Yup, thanks for suggestion, I've use **.IsBodyHtml = true.** to solve it. But i'd like to know if I can use my teammate's code without modification? Any change may cause an unexpected result.

Comment: remove using system.net.mail and add system.web.mail, then you can use the MailFormat.Html

Comment: I'm not using them at the same time, THANKS

Comment: as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) `System.Net.Mail` is obsolete too (_"SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead."_)